# Finding particular integral to $ (D^3 + 4D)y = \sin2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is to find particular integral of this differential equation

$$ (D^3 + 4D)y = \sin2x.$$

where $$ D = \frac{d}{dx} $$
Please looking for your quick tip guys.

Comment: interesting that WA fails here

Comment: @tired what is WA ? are you saying about Wronskian ?

Comment: @poush WA= Wolfram Alpha ;)

Answer (score 1):

the first step is finding the complementary solution 
$$D(D^2+4)=0$$
$$D=0$$
$$D=\pm2i$$
so the complementary solution is
$$y_c=c_1+c_2\cos2x+c_3\sin 2x$$
now assume the particular solution as follow
$$y_p=A\cos 2x+B\sin 2x$$
because the similarity with complementary solution, we should multiply the particular solution by $x$, so
$$y_p=x(A\cos 2x+B\sin 2x)$$

then you can complete the solution

Comment: No, the differential equation is not linear. Note that the derivatives are multiplied by $y$.

Comment: @mickep, yes you are right, thanks,but the question before editing was as follow $(D^3 + 4D)y = Sin2x$

Comment: @mickep so, I think the editing question by BLAZE was not ok

Comment: @mickep thanks for correcting question back to original.

Comment: @E.H.E I didn't get why you multiplied the equation with x in last part. Also looks like you are trying for WRONSKIAN method but i don't think it will be the correct method atleast for the answer i need to achieve i.e, $ - \frac{x}8 Sin(2x) $ as particular integral

Answer (score 1):

We need to find a particular solution to the following ODE:

$$(D^3 + 4D)y = \sin2x$$

Or, in the more clear notation:

$$y'''+4y' = \sin2x$$

On the first step we introduce a new function $u=y'$.

> $$u''+4u = \sin2x$$

Now, this is forced harmonic oscillator. There are a lot of ways to obtain the general (or particular) solution, but I will use a general brute force approach.

Let's represent $u$ in the form of the solution to the homogenous equation, but let the constants depend on $x$:

$$u=A(x) \cos (2x)+B(x) \sin (2x)$$

Now we can explicitly compute the second derivative to find:

> $$u''+4u=(A''+4B') \cos (2x)+(B''-4A') \sin (2x)$$

Comparing this to the original equation we have:

$$\begin{cases} A''+4B'=0 \\ B''-4A'=1 \end{cases}$$

Since we only need a particular solution, we can guess a simple one:

$$B=C_1=\text{const}, \qquad A=C_2-\frac{x}{4}=\text{const}-\frac{x}{4}$$

Setting $C_1=C_2=0$ we get a particular solution:

> $$u_p=-\frac{x}{4} \cos (2x)$$

Integrating one time, we get a final answer:

> $$y_p=-\frac{1}{16} (2x \sin (2x)+\cos(2x))$$

Answer (score 0):

Given:- (D³+4D)y=sin2x
Condition : 1/f(D), if after equal to sinax or cosax given means you have to replace D² into -(a²)
Ans-  (1/D³+4D)*sin2x
[1/D(D²+4)]*sin2x    Here, D² is replaced by -(a²) that is
D²= -(2²)
[1/D(-4+4)]*sin2x  (important first square the number and put (-) symbol.)
[1/D(0)]*sin2x [1/0]*sinx ( condition if denomerator  is zero multiply  numerator by x and differentiate f(D)).
[x/3D²+4]*sin2x ( substitute D² value)
[x/3(-4)+4]*sin2x [x/(-12+4)]*sin2x
Therefore [-x/8]*sin2x.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) for posting on the site.